# Firebase, Fabric, & Crashlytics with -ObjC linker flag without Cocoapods iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, xcode8, swift2

Trying to add `Firebase Messaging` to my iOS app that already has `Fabric/Crashlytics` and I am trying to add it without `Cocoapods`.

I followed the readme instructions in the Firebase SDK zip file and once I add the `-ObjC` linker flag to the target, it causes a duplicate symbol compile error for Fabric/Crashlytics

I then found out to use `-force_load` and pointed it to the `Firebase.h` file. This allowed me to compile, but when trying to `FIRAPP.configure()` it came up with this error:

```
2016-11-30 14:33:31.862 Parents[243] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] 
    Configuring the default app.
2016-11-30 14:33:32.029 Parents[243:24612] +[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:error:]: 
    unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3159a53c
```

Has anyone ever experienced this before? Please note I am not using Cocoapods for all three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually had the same exact problem. My awesome coworker suggested to update Fabric and Crashlytics to the latest and it worked. Try that!